# Truffle. Type index error (Error: Error: VM Exception while executing eth_call: invalid opcode)

Tags: solidity, truffle, invalid-opcode

I have got error if i try call method  getArrayData()

```
contract ManagerDb {

    struct ManagerStruct {
        bytes32 firstname;
        bytes32 lastname;
        bytes32 email;
        uint index;
    }

    mapping ( address => ManagerStruct ) Managers;
    address[] public managerIndex; // Managers

    function insertManager(
        address managerAddress,
        bytes32 firstName,
        bytes32 lastName,
        bytes32 email
    )
        returns (bool)
    {

        ManagerStruct memory newManager;
        newManager.firstname = firstName;
        newManager.lastname = lastName;
        newManager.email = email;
        newManager.index = managerIndex.push(managerAddress)-1;

        Managers[managerAddress] = newManager;
        return true;
    }

    //for example
    function getArrayData() constant returns (bytes32[] _data1) {

        uint arrLength = managerIndex.length;
        bytes32[] memory arrData1 = new bytes32[](arrLength);
        for (uint i=0; i <= arrLength; i++){
            address addr = managerIndex[i];
            ManagerStruct ms = Managers[addr];
            arrData1[i] = ms.firstname;
        }

        return (arrData1);
    }
}
```

An error occurs if I substitute the index [i]. When i use constant number managerIndex[0] and here arrData1[0] it work. What am I doing wrong
But if i use function getManager :

```
function getManager(uint index) constant returns (bytes32, address){
    ManagerStruct ms = Managers[managerIndex[index]];
    return (ms.firstname, managerIndex[index]);
}
```

I do not get error.

Comment: I'd check that index is valid, ie `index < managerIndex.length`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

array index starts from 0 so reference to  index of array.length is out of bound.

Change your for loop criteria to `i < arrLength`